# Two networks can't see computers. How to properly set them up?

Tags: networking, setup

I have two routers on my network. One `192.168.1.xxx` and the other `192.168.2.xxx`. Network 2 (`192.168.2.xxx`) can see the router on network 1 (`192.168.1.xxx`).

Network 2 computer cannot see network 1 computers.

I would like to be able to see my computer on network 2 from a computer on network 1 and vice versa. Is this possible and how would I configure it?

#### Network 1

- ASUS ZenWiFi ET8
- Access to internet
- Wi-Fi enabled
- Multiple computers and devices

#### Network 2

- Nighthawk x6 R8000 (I believe this is setup as a bridge)
- Uses Network 1 for internet access
- Controls Christmas lights
- One Computer on network

Comment: It sounds like the Netgear is *not* acting as a bridge here – if it were a bridge, it wouldn't have its own subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Your network is a bit complicated for this situation.

You have two subnets which complicates sharing and seeing other computers.  You may need to set this up with IP addressing.

Also you may have Wireless Isolation enabled on your wireless router. Check the router documentation for wireless isolation.

Consider hooking up LAN to LAN and make sure you only have ONE active DHCP Server.

Also (assuming you can) hook up Routers using Ethernet and not Wireless.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your R8000 is still configured as a router. I suppose you use it for extending the WiFi coverage.

You have two options for that.

**1. WiFi APs are connected via a cable -> Wireless AP** [Instructions WAP](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1015009/)

If both devices are connected via ethernet cable, you'll want to set the R8000 to "Wireless AP" mode. That way it will connect to your LAN via the cable and "share" the connection via WiFi.

**2. R8000 AP is connected to ET8 via WiFi -> Repeater** [Instructions Repeater](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1036082/)

In the case where you want to use the R8000 similar to a repeater, you need to set it to "Repeater" mode. It will connect to your ET8s WiFi network, and share that connection over it's own WiFi network.

The best method regarding stability would be #1, but if you cannot simply run a cable #2 should also work fine.

Note: in order for a repeater to extend your primary WiFi network properly, it needs good signal reception, so it cannot be placed too far from the first AP.

Comment: Let me add some more detail that I left out and might be important. So the full path is Modem-->Asus Mesh Router ---> Network Switch (controlled but not set that way) ---> R8000 Router --> Network Switch (not setup as controlled) --> Computer. This is all wired. because of my light network, the r8000 doesn't have wifi turned on but it has to be setup as a separate network.

Comment: @ThisGuy Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1753521/edit) your question with that information, especially with the information that you **do not** want to setup the router as a bridge. A proper network diagram would also help, as well as info if the 2 networks should be separated by a firewall or not.